# ASCII chars 29, 30 & 4 stripped from 2D Barcode

Tags: java, pdf, itext, barcode

We are using itext-1.3 to create a 2D Barcode.  The scanning programs are expecting ASCII chars 29, 30 & 4 to be used as delimiters, but it appears that these are being stripped when the barcode is created.  Is there a way to retain these characters in the barcode?

Comment: Since there really isn't a lot to go on, I am going to take a guess.  My guess is that either the PDF spec doesn't support those outright or you somehow have to escape them like in HTML.  I would google for topics on escaping non-printable characters in PDFs.

Comment: What is the link between bar codes, "ASCII chars" values, and PDFs? A bar code is an image; correct? This *image* represents values, correct? So .. the error lies in either your encoder, or in your decoder.

Comment: You're not telling us which type of 2D Barcode you're talking about (PDF417? Datamatrix> QRCode?) and that's important because not all barcodes support all characters. In some barcodes, the characters you refer to have a special meaning and they may need to be escaped.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie - this is a PDF417 barcode.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie This is a PDF417 barcode.